# SQL Server Count divide count with condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below table. I would like to count all unique Ids and then divide by a count where Role is Teacher.

Table A

```
ID    Userid    Role
 1      A        Teacher
 2      b        Teacher
 3      c        Student
```

Something like below. 
count(distinct id) / count(distinct id) When Role = Teacher

Comment: Sure, what have you done so far? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you want to count distinct roles or all roles?

Comment: Created by query and joins. select distinct A.id, a.userid, a.role from TableA A. I'm not sure what approach to take, therefore I have no work to show.

Comment: something like, count(distinct id) / Count(distinct id) when role = Teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple COUNT DISTINCT with an aggregated CASE expression. I've converted to float so that the result returns decimals but you will want to check out your data types before applying to your system.

Temp Table for sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID float, Userid nvarchar(1), Role nvarchar(7))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
(1,'A','Teacher')
,(2,'B','Teacher')
,(3,'C','Student')
```

Query

```
SELECT
COUNT(distinct td.ID) DistinctID
,SUM(CASE WHEN td.Role = 'Teacher' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Teachers
,CONVERT(float,COUNT(distinct td.ID)) / CONVERT(float,SUM(CASE WHEN td.Role = 'Teacher' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) FinalField
FROM #TestData td
```

Result

```
DistinctID  Teachers    FinalField
3           2           1.5
```